# How do I give user roles in discord when the user types a command?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am having trouble assigning a role to a user when they type in a command

Code:

```
@client.command()
async def BMOrole(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='BMO')
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send('Role given!')
```

When the user types "!BMOrole", I want to give them a role called, "BMO" and also display a message.

The error I'm receiving is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_roles'
```

Comment: Your default function parameter is passing `None` as the member, but what you want is to get the user who typed `!BMOrole` by using `ctx.author` or similar and removing the member parameter entirely.

Comment: @MarsButtfield-Addison Where do I write ctx.author?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you forget set a default user:

```py
@client.command()
async def BMOrole(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        member = ctx.author

    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='BMO')
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send('Role given!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. However, you require the `Members Intent` to access `member` as it is protected by an intent.

You will have to enable it [here](https://discord.com/developers/applications). Select the application you want it on -> Select `Bot` -> SERVER MEMBERS INTENT and then make sure it shows blue next to it. Then click Save Changes. Since you are developing your bot you might want to enable Presence intent as well to save you time later.

You will then have to edit your bot variable like so:

```py
intents = discord.Intents()
intents.all()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
```

Comment: I added the code above, when I start the bot, none of the commands work, and I don't even get an error. Do I need to place that code in a specific place, or put anything inside the brackets?

Comment: You don’t need to add it, you need to change what you already had defined before @gim

Comment: Sorry but I don't completely understand what I need to change within my code @ŁukaszKwieciński

Comment: You already had defined `client` before, instead of re-defining it again in a random place in your code you should change the definition you had before.

Comment: That's what I changed within my code, but when run it, nothing seems to work anymore

Comment: I didn't get a error, the bot just didn't work at all, but it's all good now, the other answer helped me out. Thanks for the help though :D